# Bind doesn't work on User model

Tags: php, laravel, oop, laravel-5

I have an interface called TFA and a implementation called GoogleTFA. But everytime that I try to use TFA on my User model I get this error:

> Type error: Argument 1 passed to App\Models\User::toggleTFA()
>   must implement interface App\Contracts\TFA, none given

This is my method:

```
public function toggleTFA(TFA $tfa)
   {
        /**
         * If we're disabling TFA then we reset his secret key.
         */
        if ($this->tfa === true)
            $this->tfa_secret_key = $tfa->getSecretKey();

        $this->tfa = !$this->tfa;
        $this->save();
    }
```

and this is my bind on AppServiceProvider.php:

```
public function register()
    {
        /**
         * GoogleTFA as default TFA adapter.
         */
        $this->app->bind('App\Contracts\TFA', 'App\Models\GoogleTFA');
    }
```

Any idea why I'm having this behaviour?. If I type hint TFA $tfa on any method of my controllers it works but I'm trying to keep my logic on models. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you please provide some more information like how you are calling **toggleTFA**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DI` won't work for every method. Controllers methods will use this as `Laravel` resolves them for you.

One way to get this to work in your model would be to resolve it manually:

```
$tfa = app(TFA::class);
```

If you're using this in a few different methods I would move the above to it's own method.

Alternatively, you could create a `Facade` specifically for your `TFA` implementation (the below example is assuming you'll be just placing your facades in your `App` namespace):

Create the file `app/Facades/Tfa.php` and add the following to it:

```
<?php

namespace App\Facades;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade;

class Tfa extends Facade
{
    /**
     * Get the registered name of the component.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    protected static function getFacadeAccessor()
    {
        return 'App\Contracts\TFA';
    }

}
```

Then in your `config/app.php` add the following to the `aliases` array at the bottom:

```
 'Tfs' => App\Facades\Tfs::class,
```

This way you can just call `getSecretKey` from the Facade:

```
public function toggleTFA()
{
    /**
     * If we're disabling TFA then we reset his secret key.
     */
    if ($this->tfa === true)
        $this->tfa_secret_key = Tfa::getSecretKey();

    $this->tfa = !$this->tfa;
    $this->save();
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Isn't there any better solution?

Comment: @Martin Define better

Comment: Cleanest, I'm trying to get the cleanest code. Are there any other solutions?. Can I get DI enabled on models?.

Comment: @Martin No, DI doesn't work in that way. Laravel resolves it's Controllers and `Routes` through it's `Service Container` using Reflection and since you'd just be calling the `toggleTFA()` directly it would never go through the service container. As an example try calling one of your controller methods from another method in that can. I've added an alternative (`Facades`) to my answer.